# access array elements of an array that is an element of another array

Tags: bash

.I want to define multiple arrays so that the first element [0] of each array is the name of the array, and the other two elements are simply parameters to be used later in the script, such as:

```
a0=(a0 a1 a2)
b0=(b0 b1 b2)
c0=(c0 c1 c2)
```

then using a zenity window, ask a user to select one or more of the choices presented (in this example the three array names already defined), and saving user's selection in a new array arrChoice(), like:

```
arrChoice=($(zenity --list --checklist --column="Select" --column="Selection:" FALSE "${a0[0]}" FALSE "${b0[0]}" FALSE "${c0[0]}" --multiple --separator=" "))
```

then I want to use a for loop to reference the elements of each array the user selected in the zenity prompt, like:

```
for f in "${arrChoice[@]}"; do
    newName="${f[0]}_${f[1]}" ; echo "\$newName: ${newName}"
    id="${f[2]}" ; echo "\$id: ${id}"
done
```

expected output from the echoes:

```
$a0: a0_a1
$id: a2
$b0: b0_b1
$id: b2
$c0: c0_c1
$id: c2
```

but output is only:

```
$a0: a0_
$id:
$b0: b0_
$id:
$c0: c0_
$id:
```

So the zenity window pops as desired, the user selects all three choices presented, but then the first line of each array's var assignment gets the first element appended with an underscore set ok, but each array's second element is not appended afterward, nor is the $id var assigned to each array's third element, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need indirect expansion like so:

```
for f in "${arrChoice[@]}"; do
    base=$f[0]
    middle=$f[1]
    newName="${!base}_${!middle}"
    echo "\$newName: ${newName}"
    id=$f[2]
    id=${!id}
    echo "\$id: ${id}"
done
```

See the [*Shell Parameter Expansion* section in the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 0):

What that says is `arrChoice` is not being filled the way you think it is in:

```
arrChoice=($(zenity --list --checklist --column="Select" \
--column="Selection:" FALSE "${a0[0]}" FALSE "${b0[0]}" FALSE "${c0[0]}" \
--multiple --separator=" "))
```

output `${arrChoice[@]}` and insure it is filled they way you think it is after the above. It has been a while, but I think your zenity error is that `Each entry must be separated by a newline character.` This looks strange, but give it a try:

```
arrChoice=($(zenity --list --checklist --separator=" " \
--column="Select" --column="Selection:" --print-column="Selection:" \
FALSE "${a0[0]}" \
FALSE "${b0[0]}" \
FALSE "${c0[0]}" \
))
```

See [**List Dialog**](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/list.html.en) What is `--multiple`?

Comment: I think there is no prob with the zenity pop getting user input. I can echo the array and its elements fine based on what user selects. I could have, instead of saving the user's input as array elements, manipulated zenity's output which is simply the name of the selections presented by zenity to the user separated by spaces. But I thought using an array would be more sensically efficient, except that I kinda suck at employing arrays and so create obvious errors.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. The only other thought I had was looking at the zenity docs, for a list, zenity returns the value of the `first` column upon selection unless you specify otherwise. It appeared the `--print-column="Selection:"` would return what you were looking for. Good luck.

Comment: "What is --multiple?" From <http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/zenity.1.html>: "--multiple: Allow selection of multiple filenames in file selection dialog."